# adb pull - copy whole folder to computer

Tags: adb

How do I copy a folder from my Android device to a certain folder of my computer?

If I use this command:

```
adb pull efs
```

It copies the contents of the `efs` folder to my computer's root directory. I want to copy the whole folder with its contents to a certain destination on my computer.

I have tried with the following for instance, without success:

```
adb pull efs C:\Users
```

*(my Android device is rooted)*

*I am using a window shell*

Comment: See if it helps: [How do i adb pull ALL files of a folder present in SD Card](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10060430)

Answer (score 0):

To pull files to the `C:\Users` directory with `adb` you would need to be in an elevated command prompt. If it is not a necessity to have it in the `C:\Users` directory, you could pull the files elsewhere. Ex: `adb pull C:\Users\[your username]\Desktop`.

Comment: What about Linux then? That ADB command OP noted doesn't seem to work in a Linux distro too.

Comment: To pull files to a directory in Linux with adb you would use the same syntax. 

Ex: `adb pull /path/to/files /home/[your username]/`

Although if you were not root you would not be able to pull the files to any directory.

Comment: It's not working. I tried it already. Also, I'm asking about pulling the directory itself, not just the files inside it which your comment seems to be doing.

Comment: If you want to copy the files into a folder of the same name then you could add the folder name to the end of the destination path. Ex: `adb pull /path/to/directoryA ~/directoryA/`

Comment: I have a directory named `Testing` in `/sdcard` which contains `1.sh` and `2.sh`. I can easily do `adb pull /sdcard/Testing ~/` or `adb pull /sdcard/Testing/ ~/` but both copies the two files but not the folder itself. I want `~/Testing/` automatically.

Comment: To have the two scripts be copied into a folder on your computer named Testing you can add the directory name to the end of the destination. `adb pull /sdcard/Testing/ ~/Testing/`

Comment: No! I think I'm not clear again. I don't have a folder named Testing in my Linux box.

Comment: One will be created.

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make. It does not get created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it, without difficulty or elevated command prompts. This does require reasonable familiarity with the Windows Command Prompt shell commands. If you're trying to use commands as scripts without understanding them, you'll have trouble with this.

I start with a directory `c:\android` with two subdirectories `c:\android\bin` where I have put `adb` and the rest of the platform tools, and `c:\android\pushpull` for test data.

## Set up PATH

```
c:\> PATH c:\android\bin;%PATH%
```

## Create some test data

```
c:\> cd c:\android\pushpull
c:\android\pushpull> mkdir test
c:\android\pushpull> cd test
c:\android\pushpull\test> echo foo > foo.txt
c:\android\pushpull\test> echo bar > bar.txt
c:\android\pushpull> cd ..
```

## Push it to the test area on the device

```
c:\android\pushpull> adb push test /data/local/tmp
```

## Look on the device to check it's there:

```
c:\> adb shell
$ cd /data/local/tmp
$ ls -R
.:
test

./test:
bar.txt  foo.txt
$ cat test/foo.txt
foo
$ cat test/bar.txt
bar
$ exit
```

## Remove the Windows version of the test directory

```
c:\android\pushpull> rmdir /s /q test
```

## Check it has gone

```
C:\android\pushpull>dir 
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is REDACTED
 
 Directory of C:\android\pushpull
 
25/06/2023  14:25    <DIR>          .
08/06/2023  20:25    <DIR>          ..

     Total Files Listed:
               0 File(s)             0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  REDACTED bytes free
```

## Pull the Android copy back to the Windows machine

```
c:\android\pushpull> adb pull /data/local/tmp/test .
```

The second argument to `adb pull`, which is just a ".", is the necessary detail.

## Check the copy

```
C:\android\pushpull>dir /s test
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is REDACTED
 
 Directory of C:\android\pushpull\test
 
25/06/2023  14:25    <DIR>          .
25/06/2023  14:25    <DIR>          ..
25/06/2023  14:25                 6 bar.txt
25/06/2023  14:25                 6 foo.txt
               2 File(s)             12 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)             12 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  REDACTED bytes free
```

## Notes

The key detail is realising that `adb` is a UNIX-heritage program, and really prefers you to specify where the files you'll pulling (or pushing) are to go. Trying to default this doesn't work well. Google do their Android development on Linux, and tend to assume that if you're using adb at the command line you have some experience with shells and Linux.

## Software versions

Windows 11 22H2, Android 13, Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 from Platform Tools version 34.0.3-10161052.